# tr() function not working anymore migrating from Qt 4 to Qt 5

Tags: c++, qt

I have an application where the translator is installed successfully in the usual way:

```
bool bSuccess = qApp->installTranslator(m_translator);
```

Where `m_translator` is a pointer to a class derived from `QTranslator`.

When the application is compiled with Qt 4.7.4 all the following instructions work fine:

1. `QString qTranslString = m_translator->translate("", "string_to_be_translated");`
2. `QString qTranslString = QCoreApplication::translate("", "string_to_be_translated");`
3. `QString qTranslString = tr("string_to_be_translated");`

But when the same application, same project settings, is compiled with **Qt 5.2.1**, on Windows or Linux, only number 1 is working. **The other two are not calling the translate method of `m_translator`**.

Here is a minimal example for reproducing the problem:

**minimalpbm.pro**:

```
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4) {
    QT += widgets
}

TARGET = minimalpbm
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
HEADERS += mytranslator.h
```

**mytranslator.h**:

```
#include <QTranslator>

class MyTranslator : public QTranslator
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyTranslator(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~MyTranslator();

    bool isEmpty() const;
    QString translate(const char *context, const char *sourceText, const char *comment = 0) const;

private:
};
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "mytranslator.h"

MyTranslator::MyTranslator(QObject *parent) : QTranslator(parent)
{
}

MyTranslator::~MyTranslator()
{
}

bool MyTranslator::isEmpty() const
{
    return false;
}

QString MyTranslator::translate(const char* /*context*/, const char* sourceText, const char* /*comment*/) const
{
    QString translation;

    (void) sourceText;

    translation = "Window Title";                           // No matter what the source text is we return the same translation for test

    return translation;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication qA(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow qW;                                         // Create main window

    MyTranslator *m_translator = new MyTranslator(&qW);     // Install translator
    qApp->installTranslator(m_translator);

    qW.setWindowTitle(qW.tr("ST_TITLE"));                   // Set title 
    qW.show();                                              // Show main window

    return qA.exec();                                       // Main event loop
}
```

With Qt4 the window title is "Window Title",
with Qt5 the window title is "ST_TITLE".

Any hints?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Do you get any compile errors? How do you know, that the method is not called?

Comment: No compile error. I know because debugger doesn't break within my custom `translate` (`m_translator->translate`) function.

Comment: Good would be if you could provide us with a minimal example to reproduce your issue. Otherwise we can only guess. E.g. are you actually calling `app.installTranslator(m_translator)` ? What is the scope of the m_translator object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `MyTranslator::translate` still override a `QTranslator` virtual method? When reading QT 5.2.0 documentation, the method you want to override was removed. I would suggest to try to override the translate method with 4 parameters instead of 3, so `translate(const char *context, const char *sourceText, const char *disambiguation = Q_NULLPTR, int n = -1) const`. Also put the `override` keyword behind it, so that the compiler will warn you for such issues.

Comment: `override` will even fail to compile in this case, which is even better than getting a warning.

Comment: You are right. While you were answering, I found the same thing. **Qt 4.7.4** has`virtual QString translate ( const char * context, const char * sourceText, const char * disambiguation = 0 ) const;
QString translate ( const char * context, const char * sourceText, const char * disambiguation, int n ) const;`, while **Qt 5.2.1** has just `virtual QString translate(const char * context, const char * sourceText, const char * disambiguation = 0, int n = -1) const;` so using this one in MyTranslator, for Qt5, fixes the problem. Thank you!